# How to do non-linear regression in R

Tags: r, nls

I have a bunch of data and I need to find the parameter values for [this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Op3b.png) that fit the data.

I am a complete beginner to R by the way...
How do I use the nls function properly?

```
values <- read.csv(file.choose())

nls(y~A/cos(B*(C + x))^2 + D, 
    data =values, start = c(A = 1, B=1, C=0, D=0))
```

error

```
Error in nls(y ~ A/cos(B * (C + x))^2 + D, data = values, start = c(A = 1,  : 
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

data

```
    structure(list(X = c(212.8, 219.12, 226.07, 232.39, 239.97, 247.55, 
254.5, 262.4, 269.67, 276.94, 283.89, 289.89, 297.15, 303.79, 
310.11, 317.06, 322.75, 329.06, 335.38, 341.07, 347.7, 353.71, 
359.39, 365.08, 371.71, 376.45, 382.77, 388.77, 394.46, 400.78, 
406.78, 412.78, 419.1, 425.27, 431.27, 437.59, 442.96, 448.97, 
454.65, 460.34, 465.39, 470.77, 477.08, 482.14, 486.56, 492.25, 
497.3, 502.36, 507.41, 512.47, 517.52, 522.89, 528.58, 533.95, 
539.32, 545.32, 550.7, 555.75, 561.44, 567.12, 571.86, 576.92, 
581.97, 587.03, 605.67, 611.04, 620.2, 624.94, 643.58, 648.95, 
658.43, 663.48, 673.28, 683.38, 688.12, 693.18, 697.92, 702.02, 
706.45, 711.5, 715.61, 720.35, 724.14, 737.09, 742.15, 746.89, 
750.99, 756.05, 760.16, 774.43, 779.17, 788.02, 797.5, 801.6, 
810.45, 814.87, 823.09, 831.93, 840.46, 849.31, 862.58, 866.68, 
871.42, 880.59, 885.01, 894.8, 907.44, 916.92, 925.13, 937.45, 
949.77, 958.94, 972.2, 981.68, 991.16, 1000.32, 1018.96, 1031.92, 
1044.87, 1057.82, 1066.98, 1080.88, 1096.05, 1109.96, 1120.39, 
1129.55, 1138.71, 1148.19, 1157.35, 1166.2, 1176.31, 1186.1, 
1196.21, 1207.27, 1223.38, 1239.49, 1249.92, 1265.4, 1275.19, 
1290.67, 1301.73, 1312.79, 1325.11, 1336.48, 1348.8, 1359.86, 
1372.5, 1378.5, 1390.19, 1401.88, 1413.57, 1424.63, 1437.58, 
1449.65, 1463.23, 1476.5, 1490.72, 1504.62, 1518.84, 1525.79, 
1532.42, 1539.06, 1552.01, 1565.91, 1586.76, 1600.98, 1632.89, 
1658.48, 1666.69, 1674.27, 1683.12, 1692.28, 1700.5, 1718.5, 
1727.03, 1735.25, 1745.99, 1754.2, 1763.68, 1773.78), Y = c(-806.78, 
-805.83, -804.89, -804.25, -802.36, -801.73, -800.78, -799.83, 
-797.94, -796.67, -795.41, -795.09, -793.83, -792.88, -792.25, 
-791.3, -790.35, -789.72, -788.77, -788.14, -786.88, -786.25, 
-785.61, -784.03, -783.4, -782.77, -782.14, -781.19, -780.56, 
-780.24, -779.61, -778.66, -777.72, -777.47, -776.52, -775.89, 
-775.26, -774.31, -773.68, -772.73, -772.1, -771.78, -771.78, 
-771.15, -769.89, -769.26, -768.31, -768.31, -767.68, -767.36, 
-767.04, -766.1, -765.47, -765.47, -764.52, -764.2, -763.57, 
-762.94, -762.31, -761.67, -761.36, -761.04, -760.41, -760.09, 
-758.83, -758.51, -756.94, -756.62, -755.99, -755.36, -754.72, 
-754.09, -753.46, -751.88, -752.51, -752.51, -751.88, -751.56, 
-751.56, -751.25, -751.25, -750.3, -750.3, -750.3, -749.67, -749.67, 
-749.67, -749.04, -748.72, -748.15, -748.15, -747.52, -747.2, 
-747.2, -746.89, -746.89, -746.89, -746.89, -746.25, -745.94, 
-746.25, -746.57, -745.94, -745.62, -745.31, -745.31, -745.31, 
-744.67, -745.31, -745.62, -745.62, -745.62, -746.25, -745.62, 
-746.25, -746.25, -747.2, -747.2, -747.83, -748.47, -748.78, 
-749.41, -750.04, -750.14, -751.41, -751.41, -752.36, -752.99, 
-753.3, -754.25, -754.88, -754.88, -756.15, -756.78, -758.04, 
-759.62, -760.57, -762.47, -763.41, -764.04, -764.99, -766.26, 
-767.84, -769.1, -770.05, -771, -772.57, -773.21, -774.47, -776.37, 
-777.63, -778.58, -780.47, -781.77, -783.35, -785.25, -787.14, 
-788.41, -790.3, -790.94, -791.88, -793.15, -794.73, -796.94, 
-799.47, -801.68, -806.42, -810.21, -811.15, -813.05, -814.31, 
-815.58, -817.47, -819.37, -821.58, -822.53, -824.42, -826.32, 
-827.58, -829.36)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -180L
))
```

Theres the data... SO is yelling at me because there is too much code so I need to type some more words to make it less angry at me.

Comment: Provide data that can be used

Comment: `nls(y~A/cos(B*(C + x))^2 + D, data =data, start = c(A = 1, B=1, C=0, D=0))`

Comment: @onyambu what about the squared?

Comment: Check the edit included it

Comment: @onyambu Thank you, but theres still a couple errors. How can I upload the data to SO if its in a csv?

Comment: How big is the data?

Comment: @onyambu I just put it in the question

Comment: Where is `y`? You only have `X`

Comment: @onyambu half way down

Comment: better do `data.frame(X, Y)` and paste that on your edit

Comment: @onyambu wym? where do I use that?

Comment: The error is due to the starting positions. You will have to look for better starting positions

Comment: `sec(x)` is a discontinuous function that goes to +/- infinity frequently. That could make it very hard for an optimizer. Are you sure you really need `sec()`, not `sin()` or something friendlier?

Comment: as @GregorThomas commented, sec is quit tricky. Looked alound to see as to whether `sec` can be used as an activation function but so far I am unsuccessful. Have seen a hyperbolic secant. But not secant. You should consider your activation function

Comment: @GregorThomas it needs to be sec unfortunately. Is there any way to constrain it so it only looks from a to b?

Comment: Note that this is just a FF ML algorithm with one hidden layer and `secant` activation function.

Comment: @onyambu whats the best software that could help me with this?

Comment: Can you give a little more context/reason **why** it has to be `sec(x)^2`?

Comment: I have strong reason to believe that the source that this data was collected from is heavily associated with the function `tan(x)`. This data is derived from it and the derivative of `tan(x)` is `sec^2(x)` which happens to be a U shape that resembles the plotted data.

Comment: The ploted data can easily be fit using `cos(x)^2` but not `sec(x)^2` for example. Plot the `sec(x)^2` and see how it looks like. Note that if we use `cos` then A becomes the amplitude which we can measure, B becomes the frequency, D becomes the shift and BC becomes the phase angle. Note that `sec^2 = 1/cos^2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data supplied I get an error because of the lack of equality of "x" and "X", and likewise "y" and "Y". Fixing that allows the function to run with out error:

```
> nls(y~A/cos(B*(C + x))^2 + D, 
+     data =values, start = c(A = 1, B=1, C=0, D=0))
Error in nls(y ~ A/cos(B * (C + x))^2 + D, data = values, start = c(A = 1,  : 
  parameters without starting value in 'data': y, x
> str(values)
'data.frame':   180 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X: num  213 219 226 232 240 ...
 $ Y: num  -807 -806 -805 -804 -802 ...
> nls(Y~A/cos(B*(C + X))^2 + D, 
+     data =values, start = c(A = 1, B=1, C=0, D=0))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Y ~ A/cos(B * (C + X))^2 + D
   data: values
         A          B          C          D 
 1.871e-04  1.000e+00 -2.615e-02 -7.713e+02 
 residual sum-of-squares: 86758

Number of iterations to convergence: 10 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.838e-07
```

And the fit of that model is just as bad as the fit of the model offered by Dave2e. The data looks seriously parabolic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your function is over defined.  Having both B & C as adjustable parameters is redundant and is causing the solver trouble in finding an optimal solution.  If you can remove one of these variables or define a fixed value then `nls()` has an easier time finding a solution.

Your equation becomes A/cos(B*C + B*x)^2 +D.  If we want to optimize just  variables B & C, it simplifies down to (B*C + B*x).
Let us assume your dependent variable is K which is equal to (B*C + B*x).
We can now attempt to solve K = (B1*C1 + B1*x).
We can now pick a random value for B  say B1 and find for C minimizing error of K= (B1*C1 + B1*x).
But say we chose a different B value say B2 there exist a different C value to minimize K = (B2*C2 + B2*x).
Because there is an infinite number of solutions for B & C,`nls()` is generating the error.

So try:

```
values <- read.csv("testdata.csv")

C <- 1
nls(Y~A/cos(B*(C + X))^2 + D, 
    data =values, start = c(A = 1, B=1, D=1))


Nonlinear regression model
  model: Y ~ A/cos(B * (C + X))^2 + D
   data: values
         A          B          D 
   0.03245    1.00005 -771.33115 
 residual sum-of-squares: 87192

Number of iterations to convergence: 23 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.887e-06
```

One can try several different values for C or fix B and solve for C.  In all cases there is still a large residual sum-of-squares value.

Here is a much better model:

```
model_poly <- lm(Y ~ I(X^2)+ X +1, data=values)
values$y2<- predict(model_poly, values)

ggplot(values, aes(X, Y)) +geom_point() +
   geom_point(data=values, aes(X, y2), color='red')
```

Comment: This is fixing the value of C at 1. Note that C is still a parameter to be estimated.  eg using `optim`: `optim(c(1,1,1,1), f, method = 'BFGS', data = data)` which gives 4 parameters and even a smaller SSR. We could even try other starting positions

Comment: This code runs but it doesnt fit the data. If your using the same data as me then A has to be negative.  Even if you estimate the vertex x value and set it equal to C (or the negative x value because `sec^2` is wierd) if you plot the calculated equation on a graphing calculator it will be a big mess.

Comment: @onyambu, The value of A will change based on the chosen value of C. But B & D will stay constant. My point is B & C can't both be adjustable at the same time for `nls()` to solve this problem.

Comment: That is technically not correct. Note that the change in B will impact C which and the change of A will impact D. For unidentifiability, the error will be `singular gradient matrix` and not regarding `minFactor`.  Note that The problem here lies with the activation function `sec`. eg if we just change `/cos` to `*cos` then you will be able to run the code without issues of `minFactor` for example. Yet still maintaning A, B, C, D. how do you explain that?

Comment: @onyambu, I have run the model above with several different assigned values for C, A optimized to different values, while B & D stayed constant at 1 and ~771.  I have seen minFactor error and singular gradient matrix errors related to poorly defined models. So my logic may not be sound, so please point out a different approach.

Comment: @monopoly_lover, Where did you obtain this model from?   Is X in degrees, radian or another unit? Having X a real value does not seem like trig function to match.

Comment: The point I was trying to put across is that the function `sec` is the one causing the minFactor error and not the A,B,C,D in this model.  Note that the energy landscape is too rugged such that a small pertubation might leads to being stack in a different region. Try for example creating your own fake data, and note that you can optimize it if your starting positions are close to the true values of A,B,C,D. When creating the data consider adding small error

Comment: Both the x and the y are measured in pixels. Like pixels on a screen.